# <<error type>> Strange Error

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have encountered a situation where xcode stops auto-completing and if you try to write a variable that already been defined xcode says `<< error type>>`.

Here is my error:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so you've found an xcode bug, what are you asking?

Comment: Ned to clear up some white space in your code mate :/ haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Often this indicates that your code doesn't currently compile. Swift often has trouble computing types on code that itself isn't correct. In some cases it's a bug in the compiler. Use of `AnyObject` can be particularly confusing to the compiler, and should be avoided as much as possible. In this case, `AnyObject` is required, but you should try to get it converted to a specific type quickly. Don't return `[AnyType]` for instance if you can possibly help it.

But the short answer is that the Swift compiler is still evolving, and it can't always work out types in complex situations, particularly on partial or (currently) incorrect code.

Note that you're using `var` for a lot of things that should be `let`. Unless you actually need to modify the variable, you should prefer `let`. It helps you prevent many kinds of bugs, and can be easier on the compiler to deal with (since the variable has fewer ways it can change).

Comment: Thank You for your help Rob, will try to keep the use of [AnyObject} to a minimal, hopefully the guys at Apple get these things sorted out soon.

Comment: My code compiles perfectly but I still get this issue and I'm not using AnyObject at all.

Comment: FWIW I have downloaded the code from this RW tutorial I'm on Xcode 8 and have this problem. Though I am using Swift 2.x code. I only see it if I attempt to do 'Generate interface'. Otherwise I don't see it on the original source. It creates errors on almost all `void` functions. But my code compiles without any issue

Comment: It is 2018. This s still happens.

Answer (score 33):

I have started to see same errors after Xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1 update. I have found that if you delete ModuleCache file at `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache` path, it fixes the error temporarily. And you don't have to close Xcode or the project while doing that. After deleting the file, just wait for Xcode a little to index the project files again. After that, the problem mostly resolves for some time.

As it doesn't solve the problem permanently, you should avoid writing codes causing this  according to other answers till Apple solves this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There was nothing wrong with the code in my project, but the fact that code completion was broken made me think there was.. I put this in my `.bash_profile` for easy access: `alias clearModuleCache='rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache'`

Comment: This did also do the trick for me. I also stumbled over another temporary solution which doesnt work sometimes bit also can be useful.Close XCode Delete Derived Data. Go to your project file -> Show Package Content and the delete the .xcworkspace (it will be reproduced by xcode automatically). After that open your XCode Poject again -> Clean -> Build.

This is an alternate solution which also worked for me sometimes.

Comment: While this did help resolve my issue, it ended up breaking Xcode's connection to a directory that I had added files to. The file was still there in my Mac. But it was no longer available to Xcode. I had to create a new Group (without a folder) then direct that group to the previous folder I had.

Answer (score 7):

`<<error type>>` can result from the Swift compiler not finding the header file.

## Same module:

Do you have some sort of folder structure that your source code is in? If so, try setting `Scan All Source Files for Includes` to YES.
This will make Xcode look through all of those folders when trying to find the Header file.

## Embedded Projects, multiple modules etc:

#### 1. Check the Search Paths

Have a look where the file in which your type is defined is stored.
In your Build Settings make sure that this location is included in the Search Paths.
If it is part of the User Header Search Paths, make sure, that `Always Search User Paths` is turned on.

#### 2. Check dependencies

Have a look at superclasses etc of your type. Are they included in the Search Path as well?

Comment: Sometimes you simply have to build (⌘+B) the project for Xcode to see the header file.

Answer (score 6):

Found out that the error goes away and autocomplete works again if i initialised the variable like this:

```
var name: String = "my name"
```

instead of :

```
var name = "my name" as String
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched my build destination from `Any iOS Device (arm64)` to one of the available iOS Simulators, and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try CMD-SHIFT-K followed CMD-R to clean and then run the build.

If that doesn't work, close XCode, delete derived data, and reopen XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. I tried running the whole project on an emulator, it resolved all the `<<error type>>`

Answer (score -1):

For me, simply restarting my computer resolved this issue.