# How to solve exception with Xcode 6.1 with fatal error: expectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, fatal-error

I have a problem with Swift in Xcode since two days and I don't know the answer. I searched for this problem but I've found no solution that works for me. Two days ago I did a change because of another problem, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960125/error-type-strange-error).

Now I have the problem that I will get the exception message `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when I want to handle an element of another view controller. In my little example I have two view controllers (ViewController, ViewController2). On ViewController I added a button and on ViewController2 I added a label. Both elements are referenced correctly. On clicking the button on ViewController I want to print the text of the label of ViewController2. But then I get the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Maybe I have a general problem with Xcode 6.1? How can I solve the problem?

Here is my code for ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func onClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as ViewController2;

        //IN THIS LINE I GET THE FATAL ERROR
        println(view2.label.text)
    }
}
```

Here is my code for ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: "How can I solve the problem?" Step one: You should believe the message. Either `view2` is nil or its `label` is nil or its `text` is nil. Why don't you do a little logging/debugging and find out which one it is? Step two: Then you can start asking yourself _why_ the thing that is nil is nil.

Comment: I tried a lot of things without success. This is the reasons I ask my question. I have a counter question: How is it possible to set the label text of `ViewController2` in my `ViewController`?

Comment: I believe this type of questions is the most frequent swift questions in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` gets you an instance of `ViewController2` -- it doesn't load that VC's view from the storyboard. (It's effectively the same calling `init(nibName:bundle:` on the VC class.) As such, its `@IBOutlet` variables haven't been hooked up yet. When you try to reference one, you get `nil`, and since you're referencing it through an implicitly unwrapped optional and then trying to access one of its properties, you get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" crash.

`@IBOutlet` variables are only guaranteed to have been loaded as of `viewDidLoad`. If you're instantiating the VC through `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, you'll need to tell it to load its view (by accessing its `view` property) before you can access any of the outlets.