# Return type as "<<error type>>" in header

Tags: swift

Here is a swift function I wrote,

```
func removeStackItem(stackItem: UIView) {
        guard let index = stackViewItems.indexOf(stackItem) else { return }
        self.removeStackItemAtIndex(index)
    }
```

When I look into the header of this this file it shows

```
internal func removeStackItem(stackItem: UIView) -> <<error type>>
```

Why is the return type `<<error type>>`?

I noticed this only happens for the functions where I do `return` somewhere in its implementation.

[image]

Comment: When you see `<<error type>>`, it often means indicates there is an errror somewhere, often not related the particular function/variable you're looking at. Look at earlier portions of your code or at `stackViewItems` declaration.

Comment: @Rob, Yup there was some error in the build, I cleaned it and then it got corrected thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question, it's not quite the same because yours is a return type but the idea of re-indexing your project might help:

[<<error type>> Strange Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960125/error-type-strange-error)